# How to dispose current page in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, uwp

For Example I am having 2 pages in UWP application.
with the names Mainpage and HomePage. Now I am using below statement for navigating to HomePage from MainPage.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage))
```

Now I want to dispose objects and memory of my MainPage. How Can we do that in UWP applicaiton.

Please provide your suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You do not, the garbage collector does it for you when appropriate.

Comment: It seems like its not doing. We are getting memory leakage problems because of not disposing current page.

Comment: Igor is correct! So I'd say that in this case, something in your code is causing the memory leaks!

Comment: @Sagar maybe you set navigation cache mode to enabled or required, so the page is kept in memory.

Comment: @IgorKulman Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried navigation cache mode to enabled and required as like you said it's clearing memory but my application is not working as we expected and some times automatically crashing because of adding this line. Any guess why it's behaving like this.

Comment: Set it to disabled which might help if the page is only shown once and you don't go back